# Load PHP commands / scripts from text file using PHP

Tags: php

Im looking for help with little problem of mine. I'm trying to put all PHP scripts and necessary commands / content to one text file.
That part is easy, so it's not really something I can't do :-)

But what I'm actually looking for is solution to search and run code. Well, for example I want to launch script that is on lines from number 200 to number 315. So what I really need is script, that load this file, look through it and extract and launch PHP script in chosen block. So I'm actually looking for reusable function (called from index.php).

I'm not expert. Well, I'm basically less than beginner who reusing my very old scripts where I can.

Please don't even try to recommend me anything with databases. I'm politely asking for help to find solution to my problem here, not to use what mass is using...

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Do you mean just 'include("otherfile.php");' ?

Comment: Potentially, you will need to make a new file with the subtracted PHP code block before doing the `include('tempfile.php')`. Though, with access to the shell, this may be even easier.

Comment: @MatthewKnill I'm going to call that script / function even ten times from the same place with different values / line numbers. So it's not adequate to create file for every call and quite ineffective if you overwrite temporary file every call. So I'm simply looking for something that just place the content between selected lines into string and thel launch that string as PHP script. Maybe Iwas not clean enough with what I want to do, so sorry.

Comment: @YotamOmer Sorry, but I'm lost in so many included files that I want do it this new way.

Comment: Would probably be helpful to show us some example code and an example use case.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way, it seems really complicated? You should define functions and call them by name, not execute blocks of code by line number.

Comment: As other comments have suggested, it sounds like there might be better ways to do what you are trying to do.  As you can imagine, calling chunks of code repeatedly with different inputs is extremely common, and you shouldn't have resort to peculiar approaches to do it.  Edit your question, show us a concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.